# Is this equivalence between two ways of expressing the coordinates of a rotated point useful?

Tags: trigonometry, soft-question, linear-transformations, rotations

- Using  " matrix by vector" multiplication, one can establish that the coordinates of the image ($P'$) of a point $P=(a,b)$ under a rotation by $\alpha$ radians ( counterclockwise) are :

$$ \Bigg(a\space  cos(\alpha) - b\space sin (\alpha) , a\space sin (\alpha) + b\space cos (\alpha)\Bigg)$$

- One can also find an expression using the  method consisting in considering the rotated  point $P'$  as the result of  a rotation (counterclockwise) of the original point $P=(a,b)$  on a circle of radius $D = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2}$ from an initial angle $I= \arctan( b/a)$. Thus we obtain

$$P' = \Bigg( D \space cos(I+\alpha) , D \space sin(I+\alpha)\Bigg)$$

$$= \Bigg (\sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \space cos( (\arctan \frac{b} {a}) + \alpha) , \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \space sin( (\arctan \frac{b} {a}) + \alpha) \Bigg )$$

- From this follows that :

$$ a\space  cos(\alpha) - b\space sin (\alpha) = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \space cos( (\arctan \frac{b} {a}) + \alpha)$$

and

$$ a\space sin (\alpha) + b\space cos (\alpha) = \sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \space sin( (\arctan \frac{b} {a}) + \alpha)$$

***I suppose that, in both cases,  no-one is interested in rewriting the LHS as the RHS, but is it also true the other way around?***

Comment: If you have the LHS $a\space \sin (\alpha) + b\space \cos (\alpha)$, it is a sinusoidal function, and you can find its amplitude and phase by rewriting it as $\pm\sqrt {a^2 + b^2} \sin( (\arctan \frac{b} {a}) + \alpha)$. (But be careful: you need to pick the correct sign. The atan2 function is better than arctan here.) To want to rewrite the RHS as the LHS, first you would have to encounter the RHS in a circumstance where you didn't already have the LHS.